# Chaining generators within a comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.6

Is it possible to do something like the following as a one liner in python where the resulting syntax is readable?

```
d = dict((i,i+1) for i in range(10))
d.update((i,i+2) for i in range(20,25))
```

Comment: Add two list comprehensions? But why do you want to make it one line?

Comment: Looks readable enough as is... one line isn't always better...

Comment: Use a dict comprehension instead?

Comment: @no_name I'm using Python 2.6

Comment: Since you're using Python 2.6 you should probably use `xrange()` instead of `range()` unless your ranges really are as small as those in your example code.

Comment: Too bad there's no `+` for generators...

Comment: @georg `itertools.chain` is `+` for generators, it can also be used for lists which is also efficient. I assume you already knew this.

Comment: @jamylak: sure, but just `gen + gen` would be faaaar nicer.

Comment: @georg i just got your point now right. there must be good reasons why this isn't available but I haven't thought too far into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> dict(chain(((i,i+1) for i in range(10)), 
               ((i,i+2) for i in range(20,25))))
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10, 20: 22, 21: 23, 22: 24, 23: 25, 24: 26}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
d = dict(dict((i,i+1) for i in range(10)), **dict(((i,i+2) for i in range(20,25))))
```

result:

```
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10, 20: 22, 21: 23, 22: 24, 23: 25, 24: 26}
```

Comment: @dopstar, agree i would stay with two lines, but he did asked for one line, and this is the most readable one line i could think of

Answer (score 0):

@jamylak's answer is great and should do. Anyway for this specific problem, I would probably do this:

```
d = dict((i, i+1) if i < 10 else (i, i+2) for i in range(25) if i < 10 or i >= 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives the same output:

```
d = dict((i,i+x) for x,y in [(1, range(10)), (2, range(20,25))] for i in y)
```

You could also write it with `enumerate`, so:

```
d = dict((i,i+x) for x,y in enumerate([range(10), range(20,25)], 1) for i in y)
```

But it's slightly longer and it assumes your intention is to use a smooth incrementation, which might not be the case later (?). The problem is not knowing whether you plan to extend this into an even longer expression, which would alter the requirements and affect which answer is most convenient.